# Connect Remote Cassandra Node From Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-structured-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I've trying to connect remote cassandra node with spark structured streaming.

I can connect on my local machine to existing cassandra node.

This is the code that I can be able to connect Cassandra on my local machine:

```
parsed = parsed_df \
    .withWatermark("sourceTimeStamp", "10 minutes") \
    .groupBy(
        window(parsed_df.sourceTimeStamp, "4 seconds"),
        parsed_df.id
    ) \
    .agg({"value": "avg"}) \
    .withColumnRenamed("avg(value)", "avg")\
    .withColumnRenamed("window", "sourceTime") 

def writeToCassandra(writeDF, epochId):
  writeDF.write \
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
    .mode('append')\
    .options(table="opc", keyspace="poc")\
    .save()

parsed.writeStream \
    .foreachBatch(writeToCassandra) \
    .outputMode("update") \
    .start()
```

But, I want to connect remote cassandra node. How can I specify that?

Comment: this questions code has your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46965926/how-to-handle-spark-with-multiple-cassandra-server-with-different-ssl-policy)

Answer (score 0):

To connect to the remote hosts you need to specify a single address or comma-separated list of addresses of Cassandra nodes in the `spark.cassandra.connection.host` [configuration property of Spark](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md) - this could be done either via command-line parameters (most flexible), or in your code. If the Cassandra cluster uses authentication, then you need to provide `spark.cassandra.auth.username` and `spark.cassandra.auth.password` properties as well. For SSL, and other stuff, see the [parameters reference](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md).